# Constructive feedback falling on deaf ears

Tags: management

Long story short, there have been several issues that I've had recently at work with the way things are being managed. Senior management will be setting up a workshop to explore these issues, however I have raised these issues constructively to senior management beforehand but it just seems to be continuously ignored to the point I have decided to give up trying and subsequently leaving.

What is the best way to influence people that do not listen in this situation?

Comment: `What is the best way to influence people that do not listen in this situation?` - Did not you already find out - by leaving? :)

Comment: Well that is a good point

Comment: will be in my notice period Joe

Comment: Fair enough joe

Answer (score 8):

First of all, do you report directly to these senior management? If not, skipping over your immediate manager may not be a help; any obvious unhappiness on your part will be of less importance to them, and you're missing out on getting a more influential ally on board.

"Setting up a workshop" doesn't sound like ignoring the issues. Workshops are a considerable investment when you count all the preparation time, and the time of everyone who takes part. It suggests the issues are not clear-cut and need careful consideration. It may be the beginning of the change you want, or it may be a means to postpone actually doing anything, but you don't yet know. Unless you're *really* miserable, hang in there, see what the outcome of the workshop is and make your decision based on that knowledge.

Comment: I have given feedback to Senior management, and nothing seems to be happening. A lot of talk no aciton

Answer (score 2):

They might actually be listening, but are not sure if your opinion is actually shared by others or if they are just your personal views. That might be the reason why they set up the workshop: Get more people to the table to discuss the problems you mentioned with a larger audience.

So you should participate in this workshop and use it to persuade your peers of your views. If you have a good relation with any of the other people who will participate in that workshop, you might want to start a conversation beforehand about the topics of the workshop. Convince them of your ideas so you have an ally and/or gauge what counter-arguments might come up during the workshop.

Just keep in mind that not everything can always go the way you want it to. Management has to look at the interest of a lot of different stakeholders and find a compromise between them: Yours, your colleagues, other departments, customers, suppliers, legal requirements, company image, profitability of the company and also their personal interests. You can't always have everything your way, so choose your battles wisely.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that it takes time, lots of time, for people and organizations to change.

Why? For one thing, most people don’t immediately say something like, “hey, you’re right, why didn’t I think of that?” when somebody calls them out on their behavior. People like to stick to what they know. They can be stubborn. And, losing face by admitting you’re wrong is very hard, even in non-punitive environments.

For another thing, for an organization to change takes a lot of hard work. Almost everybody must be on board with new ways of thinking and getting along with each other. Otherwise, the old ways will just creep back even with the best of intentions.

It sounds like your execs are hoping to make change. Workshops are a well-accepted first step. It’s almost certain that some of them agree with you.

It might make sense for you to stick around and see this process through. If you can distance yourself from the detailed issues, you’ll learn a lot by watching the way things unfold.